# getting pushed value of array by providing its index is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class Game {
    contestantName: string;
    tip: string;
    rounds: Round[];
    bg: any;
    logo: any;
    liveFeed: boolean;
    fontsize:string;
    fontsizeA:string;
    answerMeter:boolean;
    fontArray:string[]=[];
    constructor() {
        this.rounds = [new Round()];
        this.fontArray.push("large");
        this.fontsize="4.5vw";
        this.fontsizeA="1.8vw";
    }
}
```

I have this file in my main project and i am accessing that class by **importing** that file in **module**. I want to get the value of the pushed element by using its **index**.

```
fontSizeHandler() {

        for(i=0;i<this.game.rounds.length;i++) //value of this.game.rounds.length=1
        {
            console.log("loop");
           console.log(this.game.fontArray[0]);
        }

    }
```

I am getting **undefined value** in console i want to get the pushed value **without** poping. I tried alot but in vain kindly help me how i can achieve this functionality.

Comment: Your code is awful, but it should work. Maybe the `fontArray` property is emptied somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Probably you are not creating the instance of Game, how you define the variable? are you doing the "new Game"?

Comment: game is the instance of Game class, i got the value of array if i pop the value then i got the value of array, but i want to get the value by using its index.